# Script to limit number of checkboxes checked

Tags: javascript

I have tried several javascript scripts to limit the number of checkboxes checked in my file but nothing work.

Below is one sample I tried

```
<form id="world" name="world">
    <input type="checkbox" name="rGroup" value="1" id="r1" name="plan" />
    <label class="whatever" for="r1"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rGroup" value="2" id="r2" name="plan"/>
    <label class="whatever" for="r2"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rGroup" value="3" id="r3" name="plan"/>
    <label class="whatever" for="r3"></label>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Syntax: checkboxlimit(checkbox_reference, limit)
        checkboxlimit(document.forms.world.plan, 2)
    </script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this in Javascript or PHP? Your question seems to be confused about this.

Comment: If you are tying to set client side behaviour you need to do it in Javascript. Apparently you did try, perhaps you can post the HTML and Javascript you tried and we can see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

First off, evidently, `checkboxlimit` is not defined in your code. I did look around for that function... I am taking the code from the answer to [Javascript checkbox validation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889000/javascript-checkbox-validation-not-working).

Second, you do not have `document.forms.world.plan`. See in your HTML code, the name of the group is not `plan`, it is `rGroup`.

These are minor problems, nothing you couldn't have fixed with a little bit of understanding of the code. Which is why you have earned a free rant: While it is true that you can find code for virtually anything already done by third party (and some people will urge you to do not reinvent the wheel) and it is also true that code reutilization is important and copy and paste is the oldest form of it (after trascribing from a print, that is)... The reason it is important to learn to program and understand code is to be able to adapt it and fix it when it doesn't do what you want. Ask any professional developer (even those with little experience), they will tell you that debugging and learning take much more time than actually writing new code.

For abstract: read.

Note: Also code copied from a random person on the internet may come with security vulnerabilities, or even exploits.

In fact, the code I got from that question shows some bad practices... but whatever, I have fixed that. You can see the fixed code below:

```js
function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
  for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++){
    checkgroup[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
      var checkedcount=0;
      for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++)
      {
        checkedcount+=(checkgroup[i].checked)? 1 : 0;
        if (checkedcount>limit)
        {
          alert("You can only select a maximum of "+limit+" checkboxes");
          this.checked=false;
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

checkboxlimit(document.forms.world.rGroup, 2);
```

```html
<form id="world" name="world">
    <input type="checkbox" name="rGroup" value="1" id="r1" name="plan" />
    <label class="whatever" for="r1"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rGroup" value="2" id="r2" name="plan"/>
    <label class="whatever" for="r2"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rGroup" value="3" id="r3" name="plan"/>
    <label class="whatever" for="r3"></label>
</form>
```

The above code works, do you know how it works? Let us go see it a bit more detail:

1. Here we are simply iterating over the checkboxes:

   ```
   function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
     for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++){
       // ...
     }
   }
   ```
2. For each checkbox, we add an event handler for the click event:

   ```
   function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
     for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++){
       checkgroup[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
         // ...
       });
     }
   }
   ```
3. The event handler will iterate over the checkboxes internally:

   ```
   function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
     for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++){
       checkgroup[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
         var checkedcount=0;
         for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++)
         {
           // ...
         }
       });
     }
   }
   ```
4. And count how many of them has been checked:

   ```
   function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
     for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++){
       checkgroup[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
         var checkedcount=0;
         for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++)
         {
           checkedcount+=(checkgroup[i].checked)? 1 : 0;
           // ...
         }
       });
     }
   }
   ```
5. If we have gone over the limit, we show a message:

   ```
   function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
     for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++){
       checkgroup[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
         var checkedcount=0;
         for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++)
         {
           checkedcount+=(checkgroup[i].checked)? 1 : 0;
           if (checkedcount>limit)
           {
             alert("You can only select a maximum of "+limit+" checkboxes");
             // ...
           }
         }
       });
     }
   }
   ```
6. And uncheck the box you clicked:

   ```
   function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
     for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++){
       checkgroup[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
         var checkedcount=0;
         for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++)
         {
           checkedcount+=(checkgroup[i].checked)? 1 : 0;
           if (checkedcount>limit)
           {
             alert("You can only select a maximum of "+limit+" checkboxes");
             this.checked=false;
           }
         }
       });
     }
   }
   ```

I would like to suggest you to dig a bit deeper. Consider these exercises:

- How do you change the message?
- How do you show the message inside of an element of the page instead of a message box?
- Can you disable unchecked checkboxes when the limit has been reached?

Perhaps you may find [Getting started with the Web from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web) useful. Of course, the bulk of it for you (at least in this case) will be [the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction). There are also some third party libraries that might make it easier to work with the DOM (such as [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), which [you might not need](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
var limit = 2;//Limit of selections
var state = 0;//Selection counter

 //I detect when a common element changes
 $(".valida").change(function(){
    //Check if the item is checked
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
          if(state<limit){
           state = parseInt(state) + 1;
          }else{
           $(this).prop('checked', false); // Unchecks it
          }
        }else{
         state = parseInt(state) - 1;
        }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="valida" name="rGroup" value="1" id="r1" name="plan" />
    <label class="whatever" for="r1">Primero</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="valida" name="rGroup" value="2" id="r2" name="plan"/>
    <label class="whatever" for="r2">Segundo</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="valida" name="rGroup" value="3" id="r3" name="plan"/>
    <label class="whatever" for="r3">Tercero</label>
```

Try this way if what you are trying is on the client's side, in this way you limit the number of checkboxes in a document or in a range.

As you can see in the snipet, I can only click on 2 elements, and in order to click on another one, I must deselect a previous one